# DrawerLayout, MainActivity and orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

My main activity layout xml, looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The FrameLayout holds different fragments and all is well. Each fragment contains `setRetainInstance(true);` but since the main activity that holds everything is an activity, it doesn't have it, the result is that when an orientation change occurs, the main activity is recreated causing the all app to start again so I lose the whole idea of retaining `fragments`.

A bit more explanation: MainActivity calls fragment A when the app opens. The user opens fragment B and re-orient the screen. The main activity is recreated causing fragment A to show up again. savedInstanceState can't help me to save the last fragment that was shown because it will only force the reloading of fragment B again though I want it to retain its instance.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing? No one has encounter this problem?